# How to customize the entries in the completion menu?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, autocompletion, neovim

In insert mode, when you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> on a partially written word, a menu pops up with possible matches for completion.

How can I customize those matches ?

(I have a ruby-clangc gem that I want to use with the ruby-neovim gem in order to write my completion plugin for C/C++ code)

Comment: have a look at [`:h 'completefunc'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'completefunc')

Comment: Also look at [YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/), [vim-clang](https://github.com/justmao945/vim-clang), and [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete). Completion for C/C++ works particularly well these days.  There's also [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab), if you don't care to remember all those `Ctrl-mumble` combinations.

Comment: I knew them but I wanted to learn how to do it in vimscript. I insist to write my own in ruby (just for me) even if those that already exist work well. Don't ask why I know that it doesn't make sense. I have already my clang completion https://github.com/cedlemo/ruby-clangc/blob/master/samples/complete.rb in ruby. Just have to use it with the ruby-neovim.

Comment: Then you might want to add this information to your question.  Also explain what problem do you have with your completion code.  People are likely to misunderstand your point otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, [`the doc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-P) says:

> Find previous match for words that start with the
>   keyword in front of the cursor, looking in places
>   specified with the 'complete' option.  The found
>   keyword is inserted in front of the cursor.

You can then look at [`:h'complete'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27complete%27)
to learn how to modify the behavior of the completion.

You'll see that you have several options to make the search of the match
restricted to the current buffer, using the other loaded buffers or even looking
for the spell dictionaries.

To modify the setting simply add a line like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
set complete=.,w,b,u
```

---

Now for your completion plugin what you are looking for is a custom comlete function. Vims allows you to write such a function, for more information you should refer [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4584/1841) and to the doc:

- [`:h complete-functions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#complete-functions)
- [`:h 'completefunc'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27completefunc%27)

---

I think you might also be interested in reading [`:h ins-completion`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-completion) which explains how the different completion modes of Vim works. (There are about ten different completion modes used to complete different items, learning them can be long but it should make your completion pretty efficient in the end)